# How should I be putting exisiting java projects into a new svn repository to access via eclipse with subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN, subclipse, eclipse indigo and tortoiseSVN setup on my laptop now.  This is strictly for code on have on a local machine and SVN is setup as a localhost service instance so I have versioning for my personal development projects.

My question is, how should I be putting my projects into svn?  I started doing imports through subclipse/eclipse into the repository, but do I still need tortoise now or does it even matter how I get the projects into svn?  I did see that if the projects are already in eclipse it's not letting me do the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to submit my projects to a repository in SVN through eclipse without tortoise svn so it's not needed. To add a new project to the repository I right click on the project in eclipse and go to team and share project. Then to commit a project update to the repository I go to team and then commit. This has worked for me so far.

Comment: Yes, this wasn't a good question.  It's defaulting to Tortoise and maybe I get some extra features with it, but I don't think it's needed.